# Remove credit card details from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I helped my brother to promote his page on Facebook by paying a small amount with my credit card details.

Without any notification or alert, Facebook stored my credit card details.

Which I don't like as I don't want to store my personal details anywhere online.
When I tried to remove my credit card details by following this [link](https://www.facebook.com/help/242462812536016), it is saying that the details are of primary account and can't be removed and It said me to visit "ads manager" to remove the details instead.

As instructed, I opened "ads manager" and tried to remove my credit details. but here also I got refusal response saying that the details are of "primary account" and it can't be deleted. To delete these details I must add another credit card's details (*which should then switched as primary account*).

Logically, I should look for a fool who is willing to save his credit card details and let me remove  my details.

**This makes no sense at all!!**

Any other way around to remove my  credit card details?

PS: My brother has no credit card.

Comment: @pnuts thanks, I am on it. someone should sue FB for storing details without permission though.

Comment: Then their agreement sucks because it is against user's willingness as he/she can't even able to remove their credit card details unless they add another credit card's details. So, if once it is started then the cycle should go on. this is completely outrageous. btw, I didn't read the agreement as usual as other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want payment information held, then just deactivate your ads account.

[image]